# JavaMail MimeMessage wont send when Runnable jar is executed on a different computer

Tags: java, email, jar, jakarta-mail

I have a pretty simple JavaMail application. It works perfectly fine when I run it in Eclipse or export it as a runnable jar. When I try to run it on a different machine, no email is sent and no exceptions are thrown. In the code I have a few println()s to see where in the program it gets to.

It gets to "--- 2 ---" so I'm assuming that there is something wrong with the MimeMessage object or Session object when moved to another computer.

Any idea why this one part of the program would work on one computer but not another?

```
try {

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
});

System.out.println("--- 1 ---");

    System.out.println("--- 2 ---");

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    System.out.println("--- 3 ---");

    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    System.out.println("--- 4 ---");

    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressList);
    System.out.println("--- 5 ---");

    message.setSubject(subject + " " + LocalDateTime.now().format(mainDateFormatter));
    System.out.println("--- 6 ---");
    System.out.println(message.getSubject());

    message.setContent(html, "text/html");

    System.out.println("--- 7 ---");
    Transport.send(message);

    System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (Exception e) {     
        System.out.println(e.toString());
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: Any stacktraces being printed in console? maybe smtp host is unavailable from another PC

Comment: None at all. The console, which is outputted to a text file since it's a runnable jar, is completely blank besides the println()s.

Comment: Try to replace `System.out.println(e.toString());` with `e.printStackTrace();` rebuild jar and run new jar on another PC

Comment: How are you setting the CLASSPATH to make sure the application can see the javax.mail.jar file?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: Could the CLASSPATH be the issue if the properties and session objects are created properly? Also the only debug output is "DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.1"

Comment: I also replaced System.out.println(e.toString()); with e.printStackTrace(); Still no exception is being caught and no output recorded.

Answer (score 0):

You have to authenticate the mail server. If you use your own mail server, you may be able to set it up. So that it doesn't require authentication, but none of the public email service vendors is going to allow that, for what I hope are obvious reasons.

Comment: It is a mail server for my company. It's properly authenticated with my credentials. If the other user tests his credentials on my computer, it sends just fine.